# Email by Taxonomy Term

Tags: webforms, emails

For Drupal 8 webform, I see there's a way to specify custom email recipients based on a Select component. But I don't see a Taxonomy term reference as an option in the email handler. Is there a way to set that up in the UI? Using the UI would be ideal to let other form maintainers update the emails as needed. A taxonomy term reference is needed to also use Webform Permissions by Term.

Alternatively, if a select component was made using matching term keys, and the taxonomy term component was set to hidden/private, could the term component be populated with the select component? In that way, I could use the email handler with the select list and still use Webform Permissions by Term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can add an action handler that uses the select list to populate the Webform Permissions by Term element like I was thinking.

With a select list called Institution, using keys that match term keys in a taxonomy, the Update data with YAML section of the action handler can use this:

```
wf_permissions_by_term_element: '[webform_submission:values:institution:raw]'
```

The element gets updated on form completion and update, and individual result access is still limited by the Permissions by Term module.